# In PHP, is it possible to get a 1 dimmensional array using PDO?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

This seems like it should be (and probably is) trivial. I have a simple query:

```
SELECT Name From User;
```

When I run the query using this code:

```
$rows = $preparedStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

$Rows looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => Doug ) [1] => Array ( [Name] => John ) )
```

Is there an easy way to make the array look something like this:

```
Array( Doug, John)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the constant PDO::FETCH_COLUMN:

```
$columnNumber = 0;
$rows = $preparedStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $columnNumber);
```

This way you'll get exactly what you proposed.

You can also do the following:

```
$columnNumber = 0;
$rows = $preparedStatement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE, $columnNumber);
```

This way you'll get an array with unique values.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 2):

I think the [right answer has been given by Jaison Erick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921154/in-php-is-it-possible-to-get-a-1-dimmensional-array-using-pdo/7921208#7921208), in case you need to flatten what you've got returned (not really recommended), this would do it:

```
$flat = reset((call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $rows)));
```